# Android Fragment Transitions with GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, glsurfaceview

I have a `GLSurfaceView` in a fragment, with this being my main fragment. When I do the transition from the fragment with my GLSurfaceView to another fragment without a GLSurfaceView, the GLSurfaceView moves up a little bit before the transition starts.

I have tried setting the `GLSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true)`, it doesn't work, and it actually does more harm then good in this situation since my ads and navigation drawer becomes obscured.

I have tried hiding the Fragment hosting the GLSurfaceView, still has no effect.

I tried pausing the fragment hosting the GLSurfaceView , thus pausing the GLSurfaceView at the same time, has no effect.

When the GLSurfaceView moves up then the screen is black where the GLSurfaceView is suppose to be. It seems like the black area on the screen is specific to the fragment transitions, since if I remove the transition and simple do the replace with the fragment transaction then the glsurfaceview movement is gone. This isn't a solution though because I want the transitions in my app from one fragment to another.

Lastly, I realize that ondestroyview is being called on the fragment with the GLSurfaceView, thus destroying the view before animating the transition to the next fragment, and I think this may be the problem.

Here is some code...

Adding fragment with glsurfaceview

```
        //clear all fragments from the back stack if there are any
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); 

        //start a new deploy fragment
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new DeployFragment(), "Main Fragment")
        .commit();
```

replacing glsurfaceview fragment with the preference list fragment

```
         getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_left,
         R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_right)
        .replace(R.id.container, new SettingsFragment(), "Settings Fragment")
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
```

When transitioning from the DeployFragment (glsurfaceview fragment) to the SettingsFragment (regular list fragment) the GLSurfaceView moves up a little, maybe about the size of the height of 2 actionbars stacked on top of each other. The glsurfaceview moving up also displays a black area on the screen where the GLSurfaceView is suppose to be, but it is not.

Any ideas how to fix this issue?

---

VIDEO OF PROBLEM

http://youtu.be/RUSNBd9iuXs

right after choosing an option you see GLSurfaceView move up, revealing black space

---

Comment: Bear in mind that the SurfaceView surfaces are composited independently from all View UI elements.  Also, their positions are managed by the Window Manager, not within the app.  For the full story, see https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html

Comment: Did you find a solution to this while using Support Fragments? I'm facing the same problem right now

Answer (score 0):

The only way to animate transition for SurfaceView is to draw before content to bitmap and set it as source of imageview on top of the layout with surface. But note, because it is big bitmap if it is full screen layout for android 2.x this approach can crash your app due to lack of native heap(not java) so I recommend doing this only for ics+

Comment: So I should draw everything that is on my glsurfaceview into a bitmap and then set that bitmap to an imageview within the fragment, making sure that the imageview is full screen... and then transition to another fragment, if I understood you correctly? If this is the case, how do I render a glsurfaceview into a bitmap? Also... I think the problem that I am having is that the glsurfaceview is being destroyed when I transition to another fragment since ondestroyview is called, destroying the glsurfaceview within the fragment. I think this might be causing all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I wrapped my head around this for hours, so I will post what I believe to be a fix, but maybe not the BEST answer. What I found out is that if I use support fragments with the glsurfaceview, and try to animate transition to another fragment then I get the weird problem I describe above in the question and shown on the video.

If I use non support fragments, then this problem doesn't exist there. Using non support fragments comes with a whole lot of other problems so if anyone comes up with a fix to this problem while using support fragments then I am all ears.

**problems with using non support fragments**

- i must at least target api 11 (honeycomb) or higher, as time goes on this will become less of a problem
- i am using nested fragments, so I have a choice of mixing support with non support fragments which is nasty, or targeting api 19 or higher to use getChildFragmentManager() with non support fragments, which is also nasty.
- i am using the view pager, so looks like I have to again mix support with non support or import fragmentpageradapter for v13, which is compatible for api 13 and up.

Thanks!